# external directory is malformed when converting from URL to File

Tags: java, file, runtime.exec, processbuilder, normalize

I'm currently trying to execute a cmd in an external directory using ProcessBuilder. When I convert my URL to a File, a method in the File class that removes redundancies (File.fs.normalize) is called and reduces the "//" that I need in the "https://" of my directory to "/".

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", 
    "/C", 
    "svn", 
    "status", 
    "-v", 
    "|", 
    "findstr", 
    "/R", 
    "^C");
String svnstr = mergeUrl.toString();
File q = new File(svnstr);
pb.directory(q);
Process p = pb.start();
```

And I am receiving this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "https:\www.example.com\Archival-rel20.3"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
```

Is there anyway to salvage the URL address when converting to a `File`? The only other option I've found would be to use `Runtime`, which also passes a `File` as a directory parameter?

Comment: What is the value of `mergeUrl`?

Comment: @whowantsakookie looks that is `https:\www.example.com\Archival-rel20.3` (taken from stacktrace).

Comment: It's a valid https:// path.

Comment: The problem is here: `File q = new File(svnstr);` and the stacktrace is explicit about this: *The directory name is invalid* for being `https:\www.example.com\Archival-rel20.3`.

Comment: Right. I've changed the directory to a generic for this post, but it's a valid directory that is being loaded from 'mergeUrl', it's just missing the second backslash.

Comment: Hope that helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: Essentially you just paraphrased my question. I am looking for a solution to get the File initialization to keep my double backslash, preferably without overriding the File class. As mentioned, the normalize method within the FileSystem class (that is called by the File constructor) removes path redundancy. Any thoughts to a work around that would allow me to have a File variable with a "//" in the path?

Comment: Problem is fixed. Wasn't able to utilize the URL as the directory, but I found a local Subversion working copy in the Jenkins workspace.